# "Hamiltonian" path using Python

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I am trying to implement a recursive search for an arbitrary path (not necessarily a cycle) traversing all graph vertices using Python. Here's my code:

```
def hamilton(G, size, pt, path=[]):
    if pt not in set(path):
        path.append(pt)
        if len(path)==size:
            return path
        for pt_next in G[pt]:
            res_path = [i for i in path]
            hamilton (G, size, pt_next, res_path)
```

Here, `pt` is the starting point and `path` is the list of all previously traversed vertices not including `pt`, empty by default. The problem is, whenever such a path is found, the return statement refers to some inner call of the procedure and therefore the program does not terminate or return the path.

For example, take `G = {1:[2,3,4], 2:[1,3,4], 3:[1,2,4], 4:[1,2,3]}` (i.e. the complete 4-graph) and run `hamilton(G,4,1,[])`. It returns `None`, but if you print the path instead of returning it as a value, you'll see that it actually finds all six paths starting at 1.

If I tell the program to print the path together with the return statement, it eventually prints all such paths and hence runs much longer than needed.

How can I fix the code so that it would terminate the execution after the first suitable path is found?

Comment: You might want to [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Can you add a small example input for the function that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @bgse: Do you mean that the mutable default path argument is the catch? I removed it and nothing seems to change.

Comment: @mkrieger1: for example, take G = {1:[2,3,4], 2:[1,3,4], 3:[1,2,4], 4:[1,2,3]} (i.e. the complete 4-graph) and run hamilton(G,4,1,[]). It returns a NoneType object, but if you print the path instead of returning it as a value, you'll see that it actually finds all six paths starting at 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic mistake is that the result of the recursive call needs to be *returned*, if it didn't lead to a dead end.

In addition, `G[pt]` will raise an `IndexError` if the point `pt` has no neighbors. This can easily be fixed by using `dict.get`.

```
def hamilton(G, size, pt, path=[]):
    print('hamilton called with pt={}, path={}'.format(pt, path))
    if pt not in set(path):
        path.append(pt)
        if len(path)==size:
            return path
        for pt_next in G.get(pt, []):
            res_path = [i for i in path]
            candidate = hamilton(G, size, pt_next, res_path)
            if candidate is not None:  # skip loop or dead end
                return candidate
        print('path {} is a dead end'.format(path))
    else:
        print('pt {} already in path {}'.format(pt, path))
    # loop or dead end, None is implicitly returned
```

#### Examples

```
>>> G = {1:[2,3,4], 2:[1,3,4], 3:[1,2,4], 4:[1,2,3]}
>>> hamilton(G, 4, 1)
hamilton called with pt=1, path=[]
hamilton called with pt=2, path=[1]
hamilton called with pt=1, path=[1, 2]
pt 1 already in path [1, 2]
hamilton called with pt=3, path=[1, 2]
hamilton called with pt=1, path=[1, 2, 3]
pt 1 already in path [1, 2, 3]
hamilton called with pt=2, path=[1, 2, 3]
pt 2 already in path [1, 2, 3]
hamilton called with pt=4, path=[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```
>>> G = {1:[2], 2:[3,4], 4:[3]}
>>> hamilton(G, 4, 1)
hamilton called with pt=1, path=[]
hamilton called with pt=2, path=[1]
hamilton called with pt=3, path=[1, 2]
path [1, 2, 3] is a dead end
hamilton called with pt=4, path=[1, 2]
hamilton called with pt=3, path=[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

```
>>> G = {1:[2], 2:[3,4], 4:[3]}
>>> hamilton(G, 4, 2)
hamilton called with pt=2, path=[]
hamilton called with pt=3, path=[2]
path [2, 3] is a dead end
hamilton called with pt=4, path=[2]
hamilton called with pt=3, path=[2, 4]
path [2, 4, 3] is a dead end
path [2, 4] is a dead end
path [2] is a dead end
None
```

Note that using the function more than once can lead to wrong results because of the "mutable default argument" problem. But that's not the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'll check the other approaches, but it seems that your modification for generating one path does not always work: say, for `G={1:[2], 2:[3,4], 4:[3]}` it gets stuck at 3 and raises an error.

Comment: @Max Well spotted. There are actually two problems. The first one is trying to get the neighbors of a point that has no neighbors, which already exists in the original code. The second one is a problem in the algorithm - it turns out that what I've written isn't true either and your original version can be fixed easily. I'll need to update the answer.

Comment: ```G = {0:[1], 1:[0, 2], 2:[1, 3], 3:[2, 4, 5], 4:[3, 6], 5:[3], 6:[4]}``` Trying with this seems to be producing wrong results, just a heads up. I know this is an old solution, but I would say maybe changing the function name from hamilton in this question makes sense as either OP doesn't require a fully correct solution in terms of the hamilton path.

Comment: How do we fix the mutable default argument problem?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with no recursion DFS to search for a hamilton path from a specific vertex `start_v`.

it is made for the graph representation hashmap of arrays:

```py
G = {0:[1], 1:[0, 2], 2:[1, 3], 3:[2, 4, 5], 4:[3, 6], 5:[3], 6:[4]}
```

```py
def hamilton(graph, start_v):
  size = len(graph)
  # if None we are -unvisiting- comming back and pop v
  to_visit = [None, start_v]
  path = []
  while(to_visit):
    v = to_visit.pop()
    if v : 
      path.append(v)
      if len(path) == size:
        break
      for x in set(graph[v])-set(path):
        to_visit.append(None) # out
        to_visit.append(x) # in
    else: # if None we are comming back and pop v
      path.pop()
  return path
```

you can speed up if represent the graph by hashmap of sets:

```py
G = {0:{1}, 1:{0, 2}, 2:{1, 3}, 3:{2, 4, 5}, 4:{3, 6}, 5:{3}, 6:{4}}
```

and also maintain a visited set and for not use `set(path)`

Then the solution will be slightly faster:

```py
def hamilton(graph, start_v):
  size = len(graph)
  # if None we are -unvisiting- comming back and pop v
  to_visit = [None, start_v]
  path = []
  visited = set([])
  while(to_visit):
    v = to_visit.pop()
    if v : 
      path.append(v)
      if len(path) == size:
        break
      visited.add(v)
      for x in graph[v]-visited:
        to_visit.append(None) # out
        to_visit.append(x) # in
    else: # if None we are comming back and pop v
      visited.remove(path.pop())
  return path
```

Comment: This fails on the first iteration, trying to pop from an empty list.